# Should we have some form of tailoring tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Even with the exclusion of embroidery and cross stitch in the [sewing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sewing) tag, could it be argued that the tag is still too broad?

For example, questions about adjusting patterns to fit properly might be easier to find under a tag like [tailoring](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailoring) than sewing, because it falls under that specific field.

If you're looking for an answer to a dressmaking question, it could be harder to find because of the sewing tag also contains repair job information like fixing a hole in a teddy bear.

I know there's not a lot of traffic in sewing yet, but it's an idea I had when writing my own question earlier today.

We have a sewing-machine tag, so why not split the questions further with a tailoring tag. There are separate tags for different papercrafts after all.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't have an issue with a tag for [tailoring](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailoring) but I would expect it to be used for questions about adjusting the fit of something, not general questions about making clothing. Though, that may be a bit narrow of a mental scope for some I think that the distinction would be important.

But, with five tags to use, I don't know that it means we need to use [tailoring](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailoring) *instead of* [sewing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sewing). There's probably room for both.

So, a question about sewing quilt squares could use [sewing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sewing) and maybe [quilting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quilting) if it fits... while a question about adjusting a pattern to make it fit better could have [sewing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sewing) and [tailoring](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailoring).

That being said, until we have questions that need a tag, we do not create tags as it's not possible. Tags are deleted by the system after 24 hours if they are not currently used on a question. If you see a question that you feel needs a tag and you are unable to create one, feel free to comment on the question or use a custom moderator flag to bring it to our attention and I'm sure someone with sufficient rep will be happy to help.

---

As a note, [sewing-machine](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sewing-machine) should be limited to questions about the piece of equipment and specific ways to use it, not questions about sewing that happens to use a machine.

Comment: I used tailoring rather than dressmaking in the example as it is the better known of the pair, despite their similar meanings. Maybe dressmaking would be a better tag than tailoring as it's not as narrow and can be seen as including tailoring. I posed the questions because I was surprised the tag didn't exist. I certainly know a lot of my questions here will be dressmaking based as I'm still learning.

Comment: Yeah, the issue with dressmaking is that it sounds like it would only apply to dresses... which makes it complicated. We should see if we can come up with another option.

Comment: I agree, that's a sentiment I've always had, "why am I going on a dressmaking course to learn to make trousers?" Maybe a tag with fit in the name would work better, as fit is often used in relation to sewing clothing, "you need to improve the fit by taking in that seam"

Comment: Do you think "Garment-making" would be too industry?

Comment: No, I think it works quite well, I feel we need more opinions than just ours, I have no experience with industry sewing

Comment: I agree that using a more specific tag to narrow `sewing` is appropriate -- users may want to follow all assorted `sewing` topics, rather than remembering to favorite each new subcategory (whether that's tailoring, upholstery, stuffed animals, whatever).

Comment: Are you saying we should tailor our tags to tailoring?